# How to acess and color divs on mouseover event which are not created yet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

How do I access the divs and color them when the mouse is hovered over them. They are created inside a bigger container when the user inputs a value and i cannot access them by another fucntion.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div>   
        <div id="outer_container">
        <div id="container"> </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="user_input_container">
        <input type="color" class="user_input" name="" id="colour_picker" value="#000000">

        <button class="user_input" id="rainbow">Rainbow</button>
    <div>

        <div>
            <input class="user_input" type="range" min="2" max="100" value="16" name="options"
                id="grid_range">
        </div>

</body>
```

Javascript

```
let container = document.getElementById(`container`);
function createGrid(number) {
  totalNumber = number * number;
  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < totalNumber; i++) {
    let gridSquare = document.createElement("div");
    gridSquare.classList.add("grid_square");

    let cellwidth = container.clientWidth / number + `px`;
    let cellheight = container.clientHeight / number + `px`;

    gridSquare.style.width = `${cellwidth}`;
    gridSquare.style.height = `${cellheight}`;
    container.appendChild(gridSquare);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  createGrid(range.value);
});

let range = document.getElementById(`grid_range`);

range.addEventListener(`change`, () => {
  createGrid(range.value);
});

let color = document.getElementById(`colour_picker`);
```

What I did was just add an `eventlistener()` in the `createdGrid()` function that takes the value from `"color"` picker, but really not able to access the divs inside and get them colored by and oustside fucntions specifically for coloring.

The `eventlistener()` below is what I added inside the `for()` loop of `createdGrid` function.

```
 gridSquare.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
      event.target.style.backgroundColor = color.value;
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of inline stylyes, use CSS style sheet to style the elements. Then you can use [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators) to refer an element which doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes I've done that and I need to do this in JS.  So when the user takes the ``mouseover`` the grids their color changes. But I am not able to do that with a seperate function.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require, add a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event handler to the `gridSquare` elements you create within each loop. One event adds the `background-color` and the other removes it.

```js
let container = document.querySelector('#container');
let color = document.querySelector('#colour_picker')

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  createGrid(range.value);
});

function createGrid(number) {
  totalNumber = number * number;
  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < totalNumber; i++) {
    let gridSquare = document.createElement("div");
    gridSquare.classList.add("grid_square");

    let cellwidth = container.clientWidth / number + `px`;
    let cellheight = container.clientHeight / number + `px`;

    gridSquare.style.width = cellwidth;
    gridSquare.style.height = cellheight;
    
    gridSquare.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => e.target.style.backgroundColor = color.value);
    container.appendChild(gridSquare);
  }
}

let range = document.getElementById(`grid_range`);
range.addEventListener(`change`, () => {
  createGrid(range.value);
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.grid_square {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  display: inline-block;
}

#user_input_container {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="outer_container">
    <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="user_input_container">
    <input type="color" class="user_input" name="" id="colour_picker" value="#000000">
    <button class="user_input" id="rainbow">Rainbow</button>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input class="user_input" type="range" min="2" max="100" value="16" name="options" id="grid_range">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I worded it wrong. I want to change the color of the grids when the user takes their mouse over them.

Comment: That's what this code does...? If that's not what you want I would suggest you edit the question to give a much clearer idea of what you're trying to do

Comment: I mean, I dont wan't the color to return back to ``'transparent'`` or ``'white'`` when the mouse leaves the ``grid_squares``, I want it to stay the same even when the mouse leaves. Sorry if I am not clear enough even now, English is not my first langauage.

Comment: Ah ok, in that case you can simply remove the `mouseleave` event handler. I've updated the answer for you

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to achieve what I wanted with everyone's help.